# How does one count the packages in Ubuntu's repositories from the command-line?

Tags: apt, repository

On many distributions and the BSDs there are ways to determine the number of packages in the distro's enabled repositories, e.g. on FreeBSD you could use `pkg stats`, is there such a way with Ubuntu? I know how to count the number of *installed* packages, namely using:

```
dpkg -l | wc -l
```

which on my Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver (developmental version) system returns 1962 (and yes I know not to rely on the stability of a developmental release, as things can and often do break, this is just a system for me to satisfy my curiosity about the new release to come), but how do I count all packages in its enabled repositories?

I would imagine that `apt-cache search "*"` would return a list of all available packages, which I could then count with `wc -l` but no it returns:

```
E: Regex compilation error
```

.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`apt-cache` has a function to list all packages

```
apt-cache pkgnames | wc -l
```

returns 58218 packages with main, universe, multiverse, restricted and backports enabled on artful.

Comment: Oh rofl, I thought there was a search element to it. Sorry, nvm. It works.

Comment: `sudo` is not required for `apt-cache`

Comment: @MestreLion thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$ apt-cache stats
Total package names: 73411 (1.468 k)
[...]
```

to get that and way more information about the repositories enabled that you probably care about.